# Centos 7 + VestaCP mod rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos, centos7

First of all, i want to said, that i tried much ways from google but mod_rewrite not working!!

I tried from httpd.conf tried 1000000 way which i found on google, but still not working.

I want to remove .php from example.com/about.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This is the one of example which i tried also in .htaccess but still no luck!!!!

Finally i want example.com/about but getting 404 not found, as i said, nothing worked for me which i found on stackoverflow or google

Answer (score 1):

Seems no one posted Answer on my question, but if someone will enter to this question i resolved it :

1. Open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2. Find all "AllowOverride None" and change with "AllowOverride All"
3. Check website, if not working, restart server.

Thats works for me!!